# рекурсивный метод c двумя аргументами

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  f(1,5);
    }

static void f(int a, int b){
// нужен вывод 1 2 3 4 5. Подскажите пжл
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае смысла с этой рекурсии никакого, но все же:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        f(1, 5);
    }

    static void f(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println(a);
        if (a>=b) return;
        f(a+1,b);
    }

}
```